# How to call a function of a parent class with its own instance variables without overriding child's instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have the following code snippet.

```
class Parent(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.where = 'parent'

    def show(self): 
        print("Inside Parent", self.where) 

class Child(Parent): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.where = 'child'
        super(Child, self).show()
        self.show()

     def show(self): 
        print("Inside Child", self.where) 

# Driver's code 
obj = Child()
```

But the output is

```
Inside Parent, child
Inside Child, child
```

I wanted the output **exactly** to be (want the parent to be printed first)

```
Inside Parent, parent
Inside Child, child
```

How can I achieve it? Basically it is to call parent class in child class where parent class should use its own instance variable.

Comment: If you would want self.where to magically be 'parent' in the parent's show() and 'child' when looked up in the child's show(), you can't do that since `self` is one object and has one attribute `where`. There are not two different objects, parent and child. Perhaps you could further edit your question: what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: If you want the instance attribute to be entirely independent for Parent and Child, rename it as `__where`.  The leading double underscore causes the name to be mangled depending on what class is accessing it: `_Parent__where` from Parent, `_Child__where` from Child.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `__init__()` function of the Parent class:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.where = 'parent'

    def show(self):
        print("Inside Parent", self.where)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.where = 'child'
        self.show()
        super().__init__()
        super().show()

    def show(self):
        print("Inside Child", self.where)
```

Comment: Be aware, however, that if you follow this, a later obj.show() will display `Inside Child parent` and I'm not sure that's what anybody would want.

Comment: Yes I'm agree, maybe he need to specify what he want to achieve. 
On the other hand, in what he asked, the call of `__init__()` allows to instantiate the `where` variable of the parent

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jasonharper, it was pretty straightforward. The catch was to privatize `where` as `__where` variables in each of the parent and child class.

```
class Parent(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.__where = 'parent'

    def show(self): 
        print("Inside Parent", self.__where) 

class Child(Parent): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.__where = 'child'
        super().__init__()
        super().show()
        self.show()

    def show(self): 
        print("Inside Child", self.__where) 

# Driver's code 
obj = Child()
```

Comment: This (the double-underscore) isn't really privatization. It's called _name mangling_. The purpose of this is to prevent child classes from accidentally overriding methods of the parent class that you don't want to be overridden.

Comment: @Lagerbaer Thanks. BTW, I was wondering if I could achieve the same without writing the same `show()` function twice?

Comment: Yeah, just remove the `show` from `Child` and make the `show` in `Parent` more general: `print(f"Inside {type(self)}: {self.__where}")`

Comment: @Lagerbaer Tried but in that case, it will invariably print Parent's variable `__where`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember to call the `__init__()` method of the super class.

Note, you have tagged this as Python3, so you can just use

```
super().__init__()
super().show()
```

No need to use the name of the child class inside the parentheses in this case.

Comment: It's the same as @abdoBim. I want `Inside Parent, parent` to print first.